# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) " -ObjC "

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

I have a problem add ads Admob when I try adding ads at the last step when the trial shows the error >>>>>
: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
When i delete -ObjC ... Error goes away, but it appears to be a problem in running the application ..>>>>

This problem appears only when I try to add ads admob ...
 This problem appears only when I try to add ads admob ...
  This problem appears only when I try to add ads admob ...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6tsg.png

---

Comment: I understand if you're English isn't great, and that's OK, but could you try to make this a little more organized in terms of what your trying to ask? I tried to edit it, but had to give up. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for help asking questions.

Comment: change your architecture as "armv7", remove "armv7s" if you have.

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** Run on Xcode 5 and iOS 7.

Best tutorial of AdMob mediation

[AdMob_Mediation_Demo](https://github.com/111vandana/AdMob_Demo/archive/master.zip)

You can download it and use it in your project